# Authorization failure when updating App Engine cron with service account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have been attempting to write an App Engine Python app and manage it via a service account (because I'm doing development from a machine which I do not trust with my Google Account credentials).

I have successfully gotten the app to deploy new code versions (tip: you not only need to give the service account App Engine "Deployer" and "Service Admin" permissions in the IAM console, possibly also "Admin"--I ended up giving all three), but you also need to make sure it has write privileges on the GCS buckets used for staging and deployment, named `myapp.appspot.com` and `staging.myapp.appspot.com`*), but I cannot deploy a new `cron.yaml`. When I try:

```
$ gcloud app deploy cron.yaml 
You are about to update the following configurations:
 - myapp/cron  (from [.../myapp/cron.yaml])
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  

Updating config [cron]...failed.                                                                                    
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Server responded with code [403]:
  Forbidden Unexpected HTTP status 403.
  You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u'p~myapp').
```

If I run `gcloud app deploy` with `--verbosity=debug`, I can see that it's making a request to `https://appengine.google.com/api/cron/update?app_id=myapp` and getting back the 403.

I've tried giving the service account project editor or owner permissions, this hasn't worked. (Although if that were necessary, I'd consider it a bug.)

*: All instances of my project ID have been replaced with `myapp` in this question.

Comment: Could it be as simple as `gcloud auth login`?

Comment: Thanks, but no: I can login and push the code of the app with the service account; it's just the cron config which doesn't push.

Comment: It appears you have found a bug. We use a legacy backend for config file deployments ([dos, dispatch, queue, indexes, cron].yaml) which does not always play well with service accounts. If you file a bug on the [Cloud SDK issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list), you will get updates on the issue. If not, I'll make sure to open a bug on our private tracker. /An App Engine Googler

Comment: Thanks, filed at https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=1503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly, this was user error, but others might run into it, so it's worth me writing it up.

In the UI for IAM on the GCP Console, you add and remove roles on an account by interacting with a drop-down menu. Because this menu contains many categories of roles, it is long. You may not notice that there is a Save button within the menu, at the bottom, and if you don't see this, you will see no indication that, while you're adding and deleting roles by clicking on menu items, and seeing those roles get added and deleted from the list of currently-selected roles at the top of the menu, nothing is actually being saved to the backend.

Adding project "Owner" permission is sufficient to grant the needed cron-push rights--if you save it!

Comment: I don't see one, but is there not a narrow scope to use than `Project` -> `Owner`?

Comment: I also ran into this. I don't see anywhere mentioned that you need project owner permissions. It would be nice if this was added to the error logs. Other permission errors seem to give a clue about the context.

Comment: The answer provided by @David should be marked as the correct answer. Owner is not required for this.

Answer (score 17):

The specific role you want to add to your service account in order to deploy a new `cron.yaml` file is Cloud Scheduler Admin:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/granting-project-access#deploying_using_iam_roles

Comment: I had rest of the permissions except below. 

Cloud Scheduler > Cloud Scheduler Admin role: Permissions for uploading cron.yaml files.

Adding this worked for me.